# How to check if map could be created, if I don't use exceptions?

Tags: c++, dictionary, memory-management

I want to use `map` in **C++**, but I don't use exceptions. After using `map<int, int> my_map` in a function, how can I check if it managed to allocate memory internally (I understand that with exceptions any new inside that can't allocate memory will throw an exception)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you use exceptions, the standard containers will (if they are using their default allocators) throw `std::bad_alloc` if a memory allocation fails. If you don't catch this, then your program will terminate - so there is no way to check for success without catching the exception in this case.

If you really want to eradicate exceptions (which in my opinion is a bad idea, even if you don't want to use the Standard Library), then you will have ditch the standard containers, rewriting whatever containers you want to use a non-standard allocation model, and check for and propagate any failures. The standard containers all assume that allocation will either succeed or throw, so they cannot be used with an allocator that doesn't give that guarantee.

Comment: Good to know all this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need a non-standard allocation model, since the standard describes a nothrow version of the `new` operator.  Still, can't use the Standard Library.

Comment: @MooingDuck: by "non-standard allocation model", I just meant something that works differently to the allocator requirements specified by the standard containers library, not something outside the language standard.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you use exceptions, the C++ library uses them for allocation errors. If you really want to avoid them, you need to learn about allocators, or at least your own global operator new, and come up with some other scheme (calling a function in a global variable?) when memory is unavailable.

Comment: But you can specify `nothrow` in `new`, right? Why containers don't use it?

Comment: @gruszczy: What would a container do in the event of an error, though?

Comment: @gruszczy: standard containers don't use `new`; they use some type which meets the standard allocator requirements. One of these requirements is an `allocate` function which will either return a valid pointer, or throw an exception.

Comment: @gruszczy: as to why: exceptions are part of the language, and are much less error-prone (and also less intrusive) than other error handling mechanisms such as checking function return values; that is why the standard containers use them to report failures.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want exceptions to be thrown around, you should write your own allocator and use that in your map: `typedef std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, MyAllocator> my_map;`.

You'll have to come up with your own internal logic for handling out-of-memory situations, though, and the standard interface doesn't provide any obvious interface.

As a hybrid solution, you could write an allocator that takes memory from a static memory pool and calls some global failure handler when that's full.

Answer (score 0):

Well, exception disabled are not part of the C++ standard, so you'll be going into compiler-specific behavior. That being said, at least with GCC, the default operator new will, instead of throwing an exception if malloc() fails, simply abort the program if compiled with -fno-exceptions.